# Individual row controls populating table with while loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently very stuck on this. I have a table that generates new rows as it loops through a datatable with a while loop. Within the while loop, i have some submit buttons that get re-created on each new row. My goal is to be able to individually control each row separately but I don't know how to accomplish this. So far, i have used a hidden  to input the primary key of "id". After searching this site, i found a useful answer that showed me how to post the hidden id as a get variable and run my query with that. It works fine and updates the things I need it to, but it takes 2 page refreshes to do this. Also i had to remove the submit button and replace with a styled anchor tag to append the get variable to the url onclick. Is there anyway i can just leave my buttons or if not, accomplish the query update with only one page refresh instead of two? I'm updating only one field in the datatable. I tried to look into ajax but that's over my head. I'm open to any solution.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","maximus1127","");
$db = mysql_select_db("patients",$con);
$get=mysql_query("SELECT patientName, brand, id FROM orders WHERE onOrder=1 and dispensed = 0");
$get2=mysql_query("SELECT patientName, brand FROM orders WHERE onOrder=0 and dispensed = 0");
 if(isset($_GET['deleteId'])) {
     include ("connection.php");
   $sql =  "UPDATE `orders` SET dispensed = 2 WHERE id = '".($_GET['deleteId'])."' LIMIT 1";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
 }
?>
<?php include ("header.php"); ?>
   <table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
      <h3>On Order</h3>
    <tr>
      <th>Patient Name</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th></th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <td scope="row"><?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
    //output a row here
    echo "<form> <tr><td>".($row['patientName'])."</td> <td>".($row['brand'])."</td><td class='hide'>".($row['id'])."</td><td><div class='btn-group-sm' role='group' aria-label='Basic example'>
  <a href='?deleteId=$row[id]' class='btn btn-danger' onclick= 'pageRefresh();'>Cancel</a>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name = 'view' value='View'>
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name = 'received' value='Received'>
</div>                                            </td></form>" ;
        }?>
        </td>
    </tr>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-default">
      <h3>Received</h3>
    <tr>
      <th>Patient Name</th>
      <th>Brand</th>
      <th>Notified</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get2)) {
    //output a row here
    echo "<form><tr><td>".($row['patientName'])."</td><td>".($row['brand'])."</td><td></td> 
   <td> <input type='submit' class=' btn btn-success' value='Dispense' /></td></form>";
   }?>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

Comment: u cn probably use ajax , that will satisfy your need without refreshing the page

Comment: Have you looked at using jquery's ajax functions? https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: i have tried to use ajax but realistically i just tried to copy and paste some other template codes i found on here. I wasn't sure if i had to go and learn ajax from scratch or if there was a way with php and some tricks to accomplish it

Comment: Show some code or this question will probably be closed as too broad.

Comment: why are you mixing mysql and mysqli libraries? For a start mysql_* is long since deprecated, has security issues, and is removed entirely in PHP7. So you really shouldn't be using it for new stuff, and should be planning for migrating away from it in older code.  Second it requires two DB connections to be open, which is just pointless inefficient.

Comment: i'm actually aware of everything you just said. i'm new to this and building it in pieces as i find things that can accomplish my goal. I'm going to handle all that when it's time. Any advice that addresses the point of the question?

Comment: why not save yourself some time and write it properly the first time? Then you don't have to re-write (and more onerously, re-test) everything later.

Comment: While your suggestion is appropriate and commendable to enforce best practice in the programming community, this is my first php/sql project so this particular code is sort of a mash up of things i've written and solutions i've copy/pasted from stackoverflow to try and get where I need to be. So....any suggestions on how to accomplish what i'm looking for?

Comment: since you appear to be concerned about reducing the number of page refreshes, you already realised the answer: ajax. That's the only way to send info back to your server without refreshing the whole page. It adds some complexity but it's not _that_ hard - a page refresh makes a HTTP request to the server and receives a response. Ajax does exactly the same thing, just without refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll take a look at it. It's a new beast for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should fix your HTML. What you have shown us is not valid HTML. You cannot have a `<tr>` inside of a `<td>`... Also, you shouldn't need to have a form for each row, you could easily have one form for all your buttons. A form does append the value of the button that was used to submit it, you could use that to your advantage.

```
<tbody>
    <?php 
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($get2)) {
            //output a row here
            echo "<tr><td>".($row['patientName'])."</td><td>".($row['brand'])."</td><td></td>";
            echo "<td><button type='submit' class='btn btn-success' name='dispense_id' value='".$row['id']."' />Dispense</button></td>";
        }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: ok but wouldn't that present the same problem as the $_GET solution? would it append that value before the page was refreshed so that once the submit hits the table would be updated after one refresh?

Comment: It would be exactly like the $_GET solution, just cleaner... I don't understand what you mean by the append before page refresh. As long as you execute what you need to before querying for the table update, you should see the changes right away.